# Why isn't Fluendo software showing up in 12.04 for purchase?

Tags: software-center, canonical, fluendo

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 (32 Bit) and I have noticed that none of the previous software available for purchase from Fluendo is available. Does anyone know why?

While trying to find a answer I noticed a similar issue in the Ubuntu Forums. The response they received from Fluendo was that it was a question for Canonical and that they would pass it on to them.

I have also emailed Fluendo at info@fluendo.com. They responded by saying that this issue is on Canonical's side in the Ubuntu Software Center and that they are working on resolving this as soon as possible.

I've also posed this question in Launchpad at:

- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+question/196090 .

Comment: Why not mail info@fluendo.com, they're responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this issue is now resolved.  When you launch the Ubuntu Software Center you will need to wait a few minutes as the package information is updated.  If you continue to experience problems please report them into the launchpad URL as I am subscribed there.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: This is correct, they show up for me now.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to Ubuntu's security for an LTS. They're more choosy of what gets put in the USC. You should be able to find a Fluendo PPA, though, whether it be official or someone building for Precise.

If it was stated that Ubuntu is working on it, though, it will likely end up in official repositories sooner rather than later.